Furry little aliens in family movie
There is a movie I am trying to remember and I'm having trouble. I don't remember much, except for a few details. It was an older movie, around the time of E.T. It was almost like a mix between Ah! Real monsters (from nickelodeon) and E.T. There were these little furry alien creatures that were kind of funny and it was a family movie.
The aliens were different colors, and they were different in looks too. They were always like, arguing or something and they were trying to get back home and there was a kid, I think a boy trying to help.
I can't remember much except for one scene where the main human character and the aliens were in the woods and the lighting in the movie was kind of dark.

Gonna need waaaaaay more details than what you've provided.

I'm going to throw out a guess. Is it Ewoks: The Battle for Endor? It was a family movie that came out in 1985 (three years after E.T.), features human children, furry little aliens, and takes place mostly in the woods.


Another guess: Critters (1986).
Critters (1986) http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI0MDMyNzkyNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzE2MzUxMQ@@._V1_.jpg
It was released 4 years after E.T., featuring furry aliens. IMDb describes it as an action horror comedy, although I don't remember them being different colours (and they don't seem to be on the cover image, although another image shows one of the to be blue).

I must admit that was also my first thought when i read "furry little aliens", but the plot does not match at all, they are all black and it is definitly not a familiy movie...

@kl78 Well, it was a long time since I've watched it. :-)

I am just going on the Furry Monsters bit but - Is it the Gremlins movie? 

